# Is it possible to decompile NSIS scripts?

Tags: dll, nsis, decompiler

After extracting an NSIS installer file (setup.exe), I got a file:

```
script.bin
```

It is NSIS script file. Is there any tool or method around which can decompile it fully or partially? I'm learning about it from hours, but found nothing positive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSIS decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431254/nsis-decompiler)

Answer (score 9):

[7-zip version 15.05](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/15.05/) will decompile NSIS scripts.  Later versions do not have this feature though.

Answer (score 3):

As told in [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431269/317266) you can get the contents (the files, but not necessarily the folder structure) of a NSIS installer thanks to [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) but there is no tool to get the script that was originally compiled, or something close.

Comment: Note: [some of the NSIS-related code was removed from 7-Zip in version 15.06](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5d10a376/#6e1d/3fa3/6840/fe9c).

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool you can use to extract the nsi scripts:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsidis/

Comment: This tool is no longer under active development. But take note of the additional information and links to 7zip in that project page.